# How to safely share a global variable (cached public certificate) across a python flask app

Tags: python, flask

I need to cache a public certificate to use it to validate a JWT access tokens with every request. This public certificate changes frequently so I implemented a background function that periodically contact an API to retrieve this certificate and keep it in memory.

Given that Flask runs several threads, is this considered a safe practice to have a global variable pointing to this certificate?

What is the correct way to define this variable so functions in my resources classes can retrieve this variable?

```
project
|- app.py
|- db.py
|- models
    |- client.py
|- resources
    |- client.py
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `redis` to store the public certificate and provide a internal API for your application to refresh and get it.

```
@app.route("/public_certificate", methods=["GET"])
def get_public_certificate():

    public_certificate = None

    try:
        expires_in = redis.ttl("public_certificate")

        if expires_in <= TIMEOUT:
            refresh_public_certificate()

        public_certificate = redis.get("public_certificate")
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        return public_certificate
```

Comment: Thanks Stamaimer for your suggestion.